# Create daily log table using triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a query, the results of which are stored in a table.

```
select id, name, category, date1, count1,count2, count3
into stage
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.is =t2.id join table3 t3 on t2.id = t3.id
```

The results of this query must be stored daily in a new log table with an additional date field added that captures the datetime it was logged.
How do I create this?

Comment: You need to create a job that runs daily to copy this data to the new table, then delete out of this table after the copy

Comment: If the results are stored in a staging table (I assume because it's called `stage`) then why not modify the table and add a datetime column?

Comment: Why do you feel a "trigger" is part of a solution? Using <select ... into> contradicts the idea of a trigger.

Comment: @Brad , I do not see the SQL server agent to create the job

Comment: @JacobH, what is the way to modify the table and not erase the previous day's info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via a trigger but cannot recreate the table stage because every time you recreate it (with the into) you lose the trigger. Try this pattern:

```
create table t21 (i1 int) -- source table
create table t21s (i1 int) -- stage table
create table t2log(i1 int, when1 datetime); -- log table
go
;
create trigger t_t21s on t21s after insert
as
set nocount on
insert into t2log(i1, when1)
select inserted.i1,getdate() 
    from inserted;


    insert into t21 values (5)
    -- every day or whenever you want to fill the staging table
    truncate table t21s -- every day or period
    insert into t21s (i1) -- fill up stage table without destroying trigger

    select * from t21 -- see what is in stage

    select * from t2log -- see what is in log
```

Comment: Where in the above can I insert my query? The data is coming from the query